# Xsd2code SimpleContent not working

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd2code

so far everything went smoothly but when I tried this xsd errors came out. I have simple example:

```
<simpleType name="waluta_type">
    <restriction base="token">
        <enumeration value="PLN"/>
        <enumeration value="EUR"/>
        <enumeration value="GBP"/>
        <enumeration value="USD"/>
    </restriction>
```

```
<complexType name="cena_type">
    <simpleContent>
        <extension base="double">
            <attribute name="waluta" type="moja:waluta_type" use="required"/>
        </extension>
    </simpleContent> 
</complexType>
```

xsd2code does not generate property for waluta:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://example/MS/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://example/MS/", IsNullable = true)]
public partial class cena_type : EntityBase<cena_type>
{

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    private double valueField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public double Value { get; set; }


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public waluta_type waluta
    {
        get
        {
            return this.walutaField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.walutaField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and I receive and error that [...] does not contain a definition for 'walutaField' and no extension method 'walutaField' accepting a first argument of type 'ConsoleApplication1.cena_type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Has anyone run into the same problem and could give me a hint?

Comment: One solution is to add manually  [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    private waluta_type walutaField; but it will not work untill base in restriction is set to double, here <extension base="double">. You will receive an error counselling to change this type to string, after this it will compile correctly. All effort put me off, but to my relief, I ran into another way out - xsd.exe via command is simple and works fine. I hope this will save someone's time.

Answer (score 0):

Doing some changes in order to generate the class adding the definition to an existent xsd I've gotthis code:

```
   [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34230")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte", IsNullable=true)]
public partial class cena_type
{

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    private waluta_type walutaField;

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    private string valueField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public waluta_type waluta
    {
        get
        {
            return this.walutaField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.walutaField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I've used this definition:

```
 <xs:simpleType name="waluta_type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="PLN"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="EUR"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="GBP"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="USD"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="cena_type">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="waluta" type="ns1:waluta_type" use="required" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

So, wich is the version tha xsd2code ? I'm using the newer.

```
<NameSpace>FacturasOnline.FacadeDTE</NameSpace><Collection>List</Collection><codeType>CSharp</codeType><EnableDataBinding>False</EnableDataBinding><GenerateCloneMethod>False</GenerateCloneMethod><GenerateDataContracts>False</GenerateDataContracts><DataMemberNameArg>OnlyIfDifferent</DataMemberNameArg><DataMemberOnXmlIgnore>False</DataMemberOnXmlIgnore><CodeBaseTag>Net45</CodeBaseTag><InitializeFields>All</InitializeFields><GenerateUnusedComplexTypes>True</GenerateUnusedComplexTypes><GenerateUnusedSimpleTypes>True</GenerateUnusedSimpleTypes><GenerateXMLAttributes>True</GenerateXMLAttributes><OrderXMLAttrib>False</OrderXMLAttrib><EnableLazyLoading>False</EnableLazyLoading><VirtualProp>False</VirtualProp><PascalCase>False</PascalCase><AutomaticProperties>False</AutomaticProperties><PropNameSpecified>Default</PropNameSpecified><PrivateFieldName>EndWithField</PrivateFieldName><PrivateFieldNamePrefix></PrivateFieldNamePrefix><EnableRestriction>False</EnableRestriction><RestrictionMaxLenght>False</RestrictionMaxLenght><RestrictionRegEx>False</RestrictionRegEx><RestrictionRange>False</RestrictionRange><ValidateProperty>False</ValidateProperty><ClassNamePrefix></ClassNamePrefix><TrackingChangesEnable>False</TrackingChangesEnable><GenTrackingClasses>False</GenTrackingClasses><HidePrivateFieldInIDE>True</HidePrivateFieldInIDE><EnableSummaryComment>False</EnableSummaryComment><EnableExternalSchemasCache>False</EnableExternalSchemasCache><EnableDebug>False</EnableDebug><EnableWarn>False</EnableWarn><ExcludeImportedTypes>False</ExcludeImportedTypes><ExpandNesteadAttributeGroup>False</ExpandNesteadAttributeGroup><CleanupCode>False</CleanupCode><EnableXmlSerialization>False</EnableXmlSerialization><SerializeMethodName>Serialize</SerializeMethodName><DeserializeMethodName>Deserialize</DeserializeMethodName><SaveToFileMethodName>SaveToFile</SaveToFileMethodName><LoadFromFileMethodName>LoadFromFile</LoadFromFileMethodName><EnableEncoding>False</EnableEncoding><EnableXMLIndent>False</EnableXMLIndent><Encoder>UTF8</Encoder><Serializer>XmlSerializer</Serializer><GenerateShouldSerialize>False</GenerateShouldSerialize><BaseClassName>EntityBase</BaseClassName><UseBaseClass>False</UseBaseClass><GenBaseClass>False</GenBaseClass><CustomUsings></CustomUsings>
```